# Make divs in a row stack on top when screen size is smaller

Tags: html, css, polymer

So i Have two divs that I have figured out how to display horizontally next to eachother in a row with two columns. Once I shrink the screen size they seem to just over lap eachother. I was wondering if there is a quick way to make them stack on top of eachother once the screen size shrinks smaller than a certain size. Really I need the left item to stack on top of the right item.

Here is the html code:

```
<div id="video-section" align="center">
      <div class="video">
        <iframe src="some-video-url" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="bullets">
        <p> <h4 align="center">Text</h4>
        <ul>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Text</li>
        </ul>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
#video-section {
        max-width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        vertical-align: center;
      }

      .video {
        width: 50%;
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
      }

      .bullets {
        width: 50%;
        text-align: left;
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
      }
```

Here are images of what this looks like:

[image: desktop]

[image: mobile]

Any help is appreciated, the main goal is to stack these on top of each other once the screen size is smaller. If my code is all wrong as well I am very open to changing all of it if someone thinks that there is a more efficient way of doing this.

To give all information necessary, I am doing this in sublime text, using the polymer library with paper elements, and deploying this to a firebase hosting server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a media query that creates a break point at which the width of the elements is bumped up to 100%, like this:

```
#video-section {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: center;
}
.video {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
.bullets {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .bullets, .video {width: 100%;}
}
```

Note that I have made some small improvements on your CSS too.

Comment: Thank you! I kinda figured it was an easy fix, and i appreciate the css edits as well.

Answer (score 1):

if you are asking a quick way use the bootstrap.here is how html looks

```html
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></head><body>
<div id="video-section" align="center">
      <div class="video col-md-6">
        <iframe src="some-video-url" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="bullets col-md-6">
        <p> <h4 align="center">Text</h4>
        <ul>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Text</li>
        <li>Text</li>
        </ul>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

add

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

to header and col-md-6 class to both divs so they stackup at small screens and be horizontal in large screen.
if 2 divs are being displayed in different rows make a parent div with the 2 div's inside and add col-md-12 class to parent div.
Problem solved

Comment: Nice... But I think it requires a parent div with a class `row` to get rid of unwanted margins.

Comment: I appreciate the answer.....I like bootstrap but this is a very simple landing page, and I'm just trying to involve the least amount of libraries.... nonetheless much appreciated